# JSF selectManyCheckboxes doesn't work

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, checkbox

I have a loop via qusetions with answers. I want to fill map Map> checked Answers values

```
<ui:repeat value="#{test.questionList}" var="question">
                <h:outputText value="#{question.question}"
                    rendered="#{not empty question}" />
                <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.selectedItems[question.questionId]}"
                    layout="pageDirection" converter="#{answerConverter}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{question.questionAnswers}" var="ans"
                        itemValue="#{ans.answer}" itemLabel="#{ans.answer.answer}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>             
</ui:repeat>
```

In my bean I have

```
private Map<Long, List<Answer>> selectedItems;

    private List<Question> questionList;
    private Map<Long, List<Answer>> questionAnswerMap;

//getter- setter selectedItems
```

and

```
public Map<Long, List<Answer>> getQuestionAnswerMap() {
        if (!selectedItems.isEmpty()) {
            Set<Long> idsSet = selectedItems.keySet();
            for (Long questionId : idsSet) {
                List<Answer> answersOnPassedQuestion = selectedItems
                        .get(questionId);
                questionAnswerMap.put(questionId, answersOnPassedQuestion);
            }
        }
        return questionAnswerMap;

    }
public void setQuestionAnswerMap(Map<Long, List<Answer>> questionAnswerMap) {
    this.questionAnswerMap = questionAnswerMap;
}
```

Also I show my model class

```
public class Question implements Serializable{

    private Long questionId;
    private String question;
    private Integer complexity;
    private Set<QuestionAnswer> questionAnswers;
}
```

where `QuestionAnswer` also model class like this

```
public class QuestionAnswer implements Serializable{

    private QuestionAnswerIdentifer questionAnswerIdentifer;
    private Answer answer;
}
```

QuestionAnswerIdentifer class which service as componentId and consist from `Long answerId, Long questionId`

When I push 'pass test button' I get error

```
j_id280458803_1_639e37a6:0:j_id280458803_1_639e37cf: 
        Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

**///UPDATED**
 I try BalusC answer and write converter

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AnswerConverter implements Converter{  

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{answerService}")
    private IAnswerService  answerService;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue)
            throws ConverterException {     
        Answer answer = new Answer();
        try {
            answer =  answerService.getById(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
        } catch (DAOException | NumberFormatException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, Object  modelValue)
            throws ConverterException {     

                return String.valueOf(((Answer) modelValue).getAnswerId());
    }

    public void setAnswerService(IAnswerService answerService) {
        this.answerService = answerService;
    }
}
```

//equals and hashCode for Answer

```
  @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((answer == null) ? 0 : answer.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((answerId == null) ? 0 : answerId.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((correctness == null) ? 0 : correctness.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Answer other = (Answer) obj;
            if (answer == null) {
                if (other.answer != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!answer.equals(other.answer))
                return false;
            if (answerId == null) {
                if (other.answerId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!answerId.equals(other.answerId))
                return false;
            if (correctness == null) {
                if (other.correctness != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!correctness.equals(other.correctness))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
```

But I still get the same error validation (
I don't understand why I get this error

Comment: Please don't use `[jsf-1.2]` tag if you are actually not using JSF 1.2.

Comment: @BalusC do you say about var instead of `#{item.value}`?

Comment: You have put the `[jsf-1.2]` tag on the question. You should not do that if you are actually not using JSF 1.2. I have edited the question and removed the wrong tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Converter` which converts between the `Answer` instance and its unique `String` representation and reference it by `converter` attribute of `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`.

Here's a kickoff example (runtime checks omitted), provided that `Answer` has an `id` property representing the unique technical identifier.

```
@FacesConverter("answerConverter")
public class AnswerConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code to convert Answer to its unique String representation for usage in HTML/HTTP. E.g.
        return String.valueOf(((Answer) modelValue).getId());
    }

    @Override 
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code to convert unique String representation of Answer to concrete Answer for usage in Java/JSF. E.g.
        return yourAnswerService.find(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
    }

}
```

Note that the `@FacesConverter(forClass=Answer.class)` won't work as generic type information is lost during runtime.

#### See also:

- [JSF List Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626015/jsf-list-converter/7626170#7626170)

Comment: I can't understand the reason of my problem. That's why I can't unstand what I should write in `Converter`

Comment: You've referenced the converter as `converter="#{answerConverter}"`, right? You've properly implemented (or IDE-autogenerated) `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in the `Answer` class, right?