# Is there a way to make f:viewparam handle lists of values?

Tags: list, jsf-2, converters, viewparams

Let's say I already have a converter between a custom class `Car` and `String`.

Is there a way to elegantly make this

```
<f:viewParam name="mycars" value="#{mybean.cars}" converter="carConverter" />
```

work when `mybean.cars` is a `Set<Car>` or `List<Car>` instead of just a single `Car`, without having to write a custom converter between lists of cars and lists of strings? In other words, is there some feature of JSF that gets me out of having to parse `"[Audi,BMW,VW]"` to `["Audi","BMW","VW"]` and then convert those one by one (and vice versa)?

I'd love it if there was something like

```
<f:viewParam name="mycars" value="#{mybean.cars}" converter="carConverter" list="true" />
```

Thanks!

PS: I've seen [this post about converters and selectManyMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626015/jsf-list-converter), and in another context where I in fact use that, all works fine - selectManyMenu handles converting one by one. But right now I need viewParam to pass my list as an URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `<f:viewParam>` **does not** support nor handle a single parameter with multiple values. This is in case of Mojarra even confirmed in a comment hidden in [its `decode()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.19/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.java#UIViewParameter.decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29):

```
213    public void decode(FacesContext context) {
214        if (context == null) {
215            throw new NullPointerException();
216        }
217
218        // QUESTION can we move forward and support an array? no different than UISelectMany; perhaps need to know
219        // if the value expression is single or multi-valued
220        // ANSWER: I'd rather not right now.
221        String paramValue = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(getName());
222
223        // submitted value will stay as previous value (null on initial request) if a parameter is absent
224        if (paramValue != null) {
225            setSubmittedValue(paramValue);
226        }
227
228        rawValue = (String) getSubmittedValue();
229        setValid(true);
230
231    }
```

Your best bet on single parameter with multiple values is to use `@ManagedProperty` (in a request scoped bean!)

```
@ManagedProperty("#{paramValues.car}")
private String[] cars;
```

or perhaps manually gather it from `ExternalContext` inside `@PostConstruct`.

You may want to post a feature/enhancement request for a new `<f:viewParams>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC! "I'd rather not right now", quite funny. I'll experiment a bit with generic converters, but for now I've got it working with a specific converter between `Set<Car>` and `String`.